# Xcode 5 has no code snippets when subclassing?

Tags: ios, xcode

When I create a new class by subclassing, for example, UITableviewController, my previous Xcode version would have these code snippets commented out.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 10;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    if(!cell){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = @"Cell";

    return cell;
}
```

With Xcode 5, my implementation file is completely blank. Is this something I can change in preferences? thank you.

Comment: How to you create the object-c file? I have tried and it generate the file with code snippets.[new object-c Class and choose inherit from UITableViewController]

Comment: Thats how I create it, it knows its a subclass for UITableViewController but theres no code snippets.

Comment: Was this ever solved?  I am having this same issue.